# Some basic questions regarding the Maximum Principle for Harmonic Functions,

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions, maximum-principle

I've seen a uniqueness argument come up a few times but I don't really understand it.

The argument is that if two harmonic functions $f$ and $g$ agree on the boundary of some domain, then $f-g$ or $g-f$ is $0$ on the boundary, and from here the proofs usually state that "by the maximum principle the result follows", i.e., $f$ is unique.

How is this a result of the maximum principle?

Also, if $f$ harmonic has boundary value = $0$, can't it have *negative* values inside the domain?  This wouldn't contradict the maximum principle.

Thanks,

Comment: The maximum principle has a dual principle: the minimum principle. The maximum AND minimum occur on the boundary. To see this, replace $f$ with $-f$ which will turn maxes into mins.

Comment: Hi @CameronWilliams, $-f$ achieving its min on the boundary doesn't mean that the original $f$ achieves its min on the boundary, though, right?

Comment: Well it does because it says that its minimum occurs on the boundary, but then the maximum principle says its maximum occurs on the boundary.

Comment: Ooh, I think I see it now @CameronWilliams :-)

Comment: So then if $f$ harmonic is zero on the boundary, then it must be zero everywhere inside the domain.  And, this would also agree with the Poisson integral formula, which integrates boundary values to give interior values.  If integration along the boundary can only give zero, then the interior values must all be zero, too.  What do you think @CameronWilliams?  Thanks,

Comment: Quite right! Let me write up my answer so this question doesn't get bumped unnecessarily.

Comment: Ok awesome - thanks!! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum principle has a dual principle: the minimum principle. This can be seen by replacing $f$ with $-f$, then $-f$ is also harmonic and its maximum occurs on the boundary by the maximum principle.

Let $D$ be the domain (with boundary). $\max_{x\in D} f(x) = -\min_{x\in D}(-f)(x)$. If the minimum of $-f$ occurred at some point $y\in D$, then $\max_{x\in D}f(x) = -(-f)(y) = f(y)$. By applying the maximum principle to $f$, you know that $y$ must be on the boundary and so the minimum of $-f$ occurs on the boundary as well. Replacing $-f$ with $f$, you have the result.

This can also be verified with the Poisson integral formula and can be interpreted as saying that a harmonic function which is zero on the boundary is zero everywhere.

Comment: That's so cool @CameronWilliams - I struggled with this concept for a good couple of nights.  Thanks so much for your answer.  Can I ask you one last follow-up question, if you don't mind?  This max/min principle isn't really related to the max/min principle for complex-valued functions, right?  Typically, in complex variables, I've seen that since $f$ complex attains its max on the boundary, then $\large \frac{1}{f}$ (assuming $f$ has no zeros) also attains a max on the boundary, which implies that $f$ must also be *minimal* on the boundary.  Do you think there is any relation at all? Thanks,

Comment: There is definitely a relationship. All holomorphic functions are harmonic

Comment: Ah, of course @CameronWilliams -- the real and imaginary parts of a holomorphic function are harmonic conjugates of each other.  Thanks for the nice reminder.

Comment: For $f$ holomorphic do you know how we could establish that it has a min on the boundary, *if* it has zeroes inside the domain?  Because if it did, we couldn't look at $\large \frac{1}{f}$ and apply the maximum principle to it -- there would be division by zero.  Or is the *minimum* modulus principle only applicable if $f$ has no zeroes inside the domain?  Sorry, I'd post a new question to ask this but am concerned that I might reach my 50 question limit too soon, so I would love to hear your thoughts :-)  Thanks @CameronWilliams,

Comment: Ooh nevermind @CameronWilliams - yes it is a required assumption, that $f$ is non-vanishing, at least according to Wolfram MathWorld.  Thanks again for the discussions! Have a great day :-)